# JavaScript: Remove HTML form input group

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some issues getting the removeElement function to work as expected. I want the addElement function to add a new input group with a dropdown and a Remove button (which it does). The Remove button should call the removeElement function, removing the respective input group, which it does the first time but no more.

**Here is the Code:**

```js
  function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
   // Adds an element to the document
   var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
   var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
   newElement.setAttribute('id', elementId);
   newElement.innerHTML = html;
   p.appendChild(newElement);
  }

  function removeElement(elementId) {
   // Removes an element from the document
   var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
   element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }

  var serviceID = 0; // reset number of services added

  function addService() {
   serviceID++; // increment for UID for new input
   var html = `<div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-6"><select name="service[]" class="form-control"><option value="basic">Basic Service</option><option value="full">Full Service</option><option value="tie">Ski Tie</option></select></div><div class="form-group col-3"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="javascript:removeElement('service' + serviceID + ''); return false;" value="Remove"></div></div>`;
   addElement('services', 'div', 'service' + serviceID, html);
  }
```

```html
 <div id="services">

      <h4>Services</h4><br>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
          <select name="service[]" class="form-control">
            <option value="basic">Basic Service</option>
            <option value="full">Full Service</option>
            <option value="tie">Ski Tie</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div><br>
```

Comment: Don't add multiple script tags like that you can have it all in one script tag.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two issues in your code (based on what you have shared)

- `serviceID` needs to be **declared globally** so that `onclick` handler can access the same.
- No element is assigned the **id** as `services`

like

```
<h4 id="services">Services</h4><br>
```

Finally you need to invoke `addService` method as well.

**Demo**

```js
var serviceID = 0;
function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
  // Adds an element to the document
  var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
  var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
  newElement.setAttribute('id', elementId);
  newElement.innerHTML = html;
  p.appendChild(newElement);
}

function removeElement(elementId) {
  // Removes an element from the document
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function addService() {
  serviceID++; // increment for UID for new input
  var html = `<div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-6"><select name="service[]" class="form-control"><option value="basic">Basic Service</option><option value="full">Full Service</option><option value="tie">Ski Tie</option></select></div><div class="form-group col-3"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="javascript:removeElement('service' + serviceID + ''); return false;" value="Remove"></div></div>`;
  addElement('services', 'div', 'service' + serviceID, html);
}

addService() ;
```

```html
<h4 id="services">Services</h4><br>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-6">
      <select name="service[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="basic">Basic Service</option>
        <option value="full">Full Service</option>
        <option value="tie">Ski Tie</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like I missed the `<div>` that had the id `services` which wrapped everything. But thanks, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to do the trick. I think it might be something like the `removeElement` function not taking one away from `elementId`, but I could be wrong.